# how to include rel=preload attribute to font file inside css file

Tags: css

how to include rel=preload attribute to font file inside css file
I have css code inside css file for loading font files

```
@font-face{font-family:FontAwesome;src:url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont93e3.eot?v=4.4.0);src:url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfontd41d.eot?#iefix&v=4.4.0) format('embedded-opentype'),url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont93e3.woff2?v=4.4.0) format('woff2'),url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont93e3.woff?v=4.4.0) format('woff'),url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont93e3.ttf?v=4.4.0) format('truetype'),url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont93e3.svg?v=4.4.0#fontawesomeregular) format('svg');
```

I want to add rel=preload attribute to the fonts files for the site performance

pls some help

Answer (score 0):

You can preload fonts like this:

```html
<link rel="preload" href="../fonts/fontawesome-webfont93e3.eot?v=4.4.0" as="font" type="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

https://wp-rocket.me/blog/font-preloading-best-practices/

Comment: i tried this but didn't work still show me in chrome lighthouse "Consider using `<link rel=preload>` to prioritize fetching resources that are currently requested later in page load. " for the font files